# Ratio of $2$ definite Integrals

Tags: definite-integrals

> If $\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin (884 x)\sin (1122x)}{2\sin x}dx$ and $\displaystyle J = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{238}(x^{1768}-1)}{x^2-1}dx\;,$ Then $\displaystyle \frac{I}{J}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(884x)\times \sin(1122x)}{2\sin x}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos (238 x)- \cos(2006x)}{4\sin x}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos (238 x)}{4\sin x}dx-\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(2006x)}{4\sin x}dx=I_{119} -I_{1003}$$

Where $$I_k=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos (2k) x}{4\sin x}dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos (2k) x}{4\sin x}+\frac{\cos (2k\pi-2k\pi x)}{4\sin (\pi-x)}dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos (2k) x}{2\sin x}dx$$

$$\displaystyle \implies I_k-I_{k-1}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos (2k) x-\cos 2(k-1)x}{2\sin x}dx=-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2\sin (2k-1) x\sin x}{2\sin x}dx$$

$$=-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin (2k-1)dx=\biggl(\frac {\cos (2k-1)x}{2k-1}\biggr)_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=-\frac {1}{2k-1}$$

$$\implies I_{k-1}-I_{k}=\frac {1}{2k-1}$$

Now plug $k=120,121,122,\cdots,1003$ in the above expression and add all the equations we get

$$I_{119}-I_{1003}=\sum_{k=120}^{1003} \frac {1}{2k-1}$$

Hence $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(884x)\times \sin(1122x)}{2\sin x}dx=\sum_{k=120}^{1003} \frac {1}{2k-1}$$

How can i solve Second Integral , Help required, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Put $x=\sin y$

$$J=-\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\sin^{2006}y-\sin^{238}y}{\cos y}dy=F_{119}-F_{1003}$$

Now $$F_{m+2}-F_m=\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\sin^{m+2}y-\sin^my}{\cos y}dy=-\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^m y\cos y\ dy$$

Put $\sin y=u$

Comment: Thanks lab bhattacharjee, But these two integrals are not equal , I did not understand where i have done mistake

Comment: Thanks lab bhattacharjee got it.